# Move data Excel to Right Column after 40 Rows Data using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, gridview, export-to-excel

I want ask about export data from Gridviews to Excel. For exp if I have 500 data in gridview, I want my data can move to right column after 40 rows because if I printout so many empty space in right side. This my code to export gridview to Excel.

```
private void exToExcel()
    {
        if (RekapdataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application XcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet lembarKerja = XcelApp.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
            XcelApp.Cells[1, 1] = "Tanggal";
            XcelApp.Cells[1, 2] = labelTglRekap.Text;
            XcelApp.Cells[2, 1] = "Kode Pemain";
            XcelApp.Cells[2, 2] = labelKodePemain.Text;


            int x = RekapdataGridView.RowCount;

            for (int i = 1; i < RekapdataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                XcelApp.Cells[4, i] = RekapdataGridView.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < RekapdataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < RekapdataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    //"'{0}" untuk menampilkan 0 pada awal angka
                    XcelApp.Cells[i + 5, j + 1] = string.Format("'{0}",RekapdataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);                  
                }
            }

            //bold pada judul table
            lembarKerja.Range["A4"].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

            //untuk menampilkan border pada excel
            var batas = x + 4;
            Excel.Range last = lembarKerja.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
            Excel.Range cellRange = lembarKerja.get_Range("A4", last);
            Excel.Borders xborders = cellRange.Borders;
            xborders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
            xborders.Weight = 2d;


            XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();            
            XcelApp.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

This is image in my Excel:

[image]

I want change to:

[image]

After 4 time move to right column F hope my title in cell "a1:b2" can repeat to next page like function Print Titles in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Excel tends to be most functional when all like data is in a the same column or row.

If I understand correctly, I would count till you reach 40 cells written to the column and then add 2 to the column int.

```
for (int i = 0; i < RekapdataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < RekapdataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        count++;

        if(count == 40)
        {
            count = 0;
            columnnumb = columnnumb + 2;
        }

        XcelApp.Cells[i + 5, j + columnnumb] = string.Format("'{0}", RekapdataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);                  
    }
}
```

Something like this, I haven't tested this, but the idea is to move the column number over every time you have printed 40 lines in the current column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i don't understand count++; That for row.count or clolumn.count ?